# How to cast datetimeoffset to datetime in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-6, datetimeoffset

It seems like a simple thing to do, but EF doesn't support properties like `DateTimeOffset.DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset.LocalDateTime` or even `DateTime.Date`.  I'm trying to filter a DateTimeOffset type field by the DateTime component only (i.e. the 'local' DateTime), which is a simple thing to do in plain sql: `where cast(x as datetime) = '2016-12-14'`.

There is a `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, but no corresponding `TruncateOffset`.

There just doesn't seem to be any way to cast or convert a `DateTimeOffset` object to a normal `DateTime` object that works in linq-to-entities. The only conversion is an implicit one from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset`, but not the other way around.

Comment: `TruncateTime` has two overloads `TruncateTime(Nullable<DateTimeOffset>)` and `TruncateTime(Nullable<DateTime>)`

Comment: Which both discard the TIME.  I want to get the DateTime (both date and time) of a DateTimeOffset, without the Offset.  It's completely useless to support the type if you cannot get at the DateTime part of the DateTimeOffset.  A DateTimeOffset is equivalent to a UTC DateTime, it just separates the DateTime from the Offset.  And if I cannot query the DateTime part of the DateTimeOffset in EF, the it's worthless.  LIke I said, in plain SQL, it's simply `cast(x as datetime)` where x is a DateTimeOffset field.  They really need a TruncateOffset function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757384/convert-datetimeoffset-to-datetime-in-linq-query

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **DbFunctions.CreateDateTime** to strip off the offset, for example:

```
...
.Select(e => new MyClass {                                      
  MyDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.MyDateTimeOffset.Year,
                                      e.MyDateTimeOffset.Month,
                                      e.MyDateTimeOffset.Day,
                                      e.MyDateTimeOffset.Hour,
                                      e.MyDateTimeOffset.Minute,
                                      e.MyDateTimeOffset.Second)
...
```

As you might suspect, this creates some truly awful SQL, ie:

```
convert (datetime2,right('000' + convert(varchar(255), DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[MyDateTimeOffset])), 4) + '-' + convert(varchar(255), DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[MyDateTimeOffset])) + '-' + convert(varchar(255), DATEPART (day, [Extent1].[MyDateTimeOffset])) + ' ' + convert(varchar(255), DATEPART (hour, [Extent1].[MyDateTimeOffset])) + ':' + convert(varchar(255), DATEPART (minute, [Extent1].[MyDateTimeOffset])) + ':' + str( CAST( DATEPART (second, [Extent1].[MyDateTimeOffset]) AS float), 10, 7), 121) AS [C2]
```

However it will give you what you want.

One caveat is that this will completely strip-off / ignore the offset (as the OP requested).

Comment: But this doesn't convert the datetimeoffset to a local datetime, it just uses the values of the datetimeoffset.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` and was able to solve it using `DbFunctions.DiffDays`

Here is an example:

```
DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTimeOffset.Now, x.EventDate) == 0
```

When using DbFunctions.DiffDays, the offset is not taken into account. Here is the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220092(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: How does this help in answering the OP's question?  How did you go from using DiffDays to actually getting the DateTime component out of a DateTimeOffset?

Comment: I had written: "When using DbFunctions.DiffDays, the offset is not taken into account". The OP had an example of: where cast(x as datetime) = '2016-12-14'. You would solve this with: DbFunctions.DiffDays('2016-12-14', x.EFTableDate) == 0 .. Does that clarify?

Comment: gotcha - makes perfect sense - I was focused on the conversion to DateTime and missed that he was looking to use this in a where clause.