# Convert DateTimeOffset to DateTime in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have DateTimeOffset column in my table, when I fetch data from this table by linq query and use

```
 (from c in this.dbContext.SomeTable
  where c.Id == someId
  select new SomeModel()
  {
       Id = c.Id,
       Name = c.Name,
       StartDate = c.StartDate.DateTime // <-- problematic line  
  }
```

in my Select, I get following exception :

> The specified type member 'DateTime' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Is it possible to convert DateTimeOffset to DateTime while fetch data in query?
I do not see any function in DbFunctions for this.
Do I have to fetch data with DateTimeOffset and do :

```
data.StartDate = data.StartDate.DateTime
```

there must be simplier solution

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way but you could in theory select into an anonymous object, do a `ToList` (to force a fetch of the results)  and then do the select you have there at which point your call to DateTime will be in LINQ to objects and not LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 3):

Since projection (i.e. `Select`) is the last operation in the chain, you can transfer the data to memory before performing it. This way you would not need support in LINQ to Entities:

```
res = this.dbContext.SomeTable
    .Where(c => c.Id == someId)
    .AsEnumerable() // The following "Select" run in memory
    .Select(c => new SomeModel {
        Id = c.Id
    ,   Name = c.Name
    ,   StartDate = c.StartDate.DateTime // No problem here 
    });
```

Comment: What if it's not the last operation in the chain? Telerik MVC DataSourceRequest (a filter) only works on viewmodels afaik.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code:**

```
(from c in this.dbContext.SomeTable
  where c.Id == someId
  select new SomeModel()
  {
       Id = c.Id,
       Name = c.Name,
       StartDate = c.StartDate!=null ? c.StartDate.DateTime:null // <-- Check null
  }
```

Comment: it is not possible, by the way it is nicer to do StartDate = c.StartDate?.DateTime